# Determine the sum of the Telescopic serie

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I Can't see where the serie goes.

I opened N terms, but I'm having some issues. If someone can help. The serie is $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2-1}$$

Comment: Why don't u try with $$\dfrac2{n^2-1}=\dfrac{n+1-(n-1)}{(n+1)(n-1)}=f(n-1)-f(n+1)$$ where $$f(m)=\dfrac1m$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
Can you see how this is a telescopic sum?

**Addendum:** Looking at the $N$-th partial sum we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)&=\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+...+\\&\ \ \ \ \ \left(\frac{1}{N-3}-\frac{1}{N-1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{N-2}-\frac{1}{N}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)\\&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\left(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+...\end{align}$$
Do you see which terms will cancel out (Hint: there should be two terms left over on each end of the sum)?

Comment: I did the partial fraction decomposition, but when i opened term by term i can't see the result

Comment: @HamiltonJunior see my addendum

Comment: now i saw and two terms left if i correct. $ 1 $ and $ \frac{1}{2}$, Correct?

Comment: Those are not quite the only terms left in the $N$-th partial sum. However, after taking the limit to infinity these are the remaining terms. Can you see what the other two terms remaining in the $N$-th partial sum should be?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{N}$ and $\frac{1}{N-3}$ ?

Comment: Close. The $\frac{1}{N-3}$ term will actually be cancelled out by a $-\frac{1}{N-3}$ term, two brackets before the one seen above. The remaining terms are $-\frac{1}{N}$ and $-\frac{1}{N+1}$. These are the last two terms, which are not cancelled out because all cancellations occur between numbers in terms (brackets) that are two spaces apart.

Comment: I understand cleary now, Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

$S_k=\sum_{n=2}^k\{\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\}$

$=1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}$

Hence series converges to $\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\int_0^1x^{n-2}-x^ndx=\frac{2}{n^2-1}$$
using this hint we will get
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{2}{n^2-1}}=\int_0^1{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x^{n-2}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x^ndx}\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\int_0^1{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x^ndx}\\ \ \ \ =\int_0^1{(1+x)dx}$$This is an integral one can do via standard calculus methods.